# How to convert your message(role) to @<role> on channel? (discord.js)

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm writing discord bot.
When I write `<role>` on channel I'd like to check if this role exists and rewrite/save as var `@<role>` (ping all members that have this role). But I don't know how.
Thanks for help;)

Answer (score 0):

I found something but it doesn't work well. It never finds role which exists on that server. Here is code

```
const roleArgs = msgef;
const role = msgef.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === roleArgs);
                                if (!role) {return msessage.reply ('There is not such role!');  return; } 
    ping = "<@&" + role.id + ">" ;
    message.channel.send(ping);
```

Thanks for help ;)